# Contour count rows with several variables

Tags: foundry-contour

I would like to count the number of rows which have the same 3 variables

e.g.
Name, Country, City

my current proposal was the code below, but there i was only able to select one variable but i need all three.

count("Personal ID") OVER (
PARTITION BY "Name")

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.